# mod_rewrite rule in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a link

```
http://example.com/fightblog/home/heading.php?id=15&title=whatever
```

After using this rule

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fightblog/home/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /heading\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ heading.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

I am able to redirect to

```
http://example.com/fightblog/home/15/whatever
```

which is correct. But my query is, its giving error 404. page not found.

**How can I solve this error? and I also want the id value in $_GET['id'] after redirection**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rewrite rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w.-]+)/([\w.-]+)/?$ heading.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

So that both parameters accept word character or hyphen.

Comment: It is strange because same rule works fine on my Apache. Make sure you don't have any other rule before this other than redirect rule.

Comment: there is no other rule. You can assume title as "ICC-champions-trophy-final-2017.-India-vs-Pakistan". Where to keep this file? inside fightblog directory or home directory?

Comment: its working under home directory after removing "." from title you can see dot between 2017 and India in title but css and js files are not loading

Comment: Yeah thats perfect. Thanks